# How to add a 3rd party script code into Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add the snippet provided by Segment Analytics into `nuxt.config.js` but I'm getting the following error:

> FATAL  $config is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
head: {
  script: [
    {
      hid: 'segment-script',
      innerHTML: `
        !function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)...
        analytics.load(${this.$config.segmentApiSecret});
        analytics.page();
        }}();
      `,
      type: 'text/javascript',
      charset: 'utf-8'
    }
  ]
},
privateRuntimeConfig: {
  segmentApiSecret: process.env.SEGMENT_API_SECRET
},
```

Answer (score 9):

## How to load external JavaScript scripts

- If you are planning to import a `.js` file, I do recommend this article: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/
- Use [inject](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context) to add an NPM package to Nuxt's context, this [blog post](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-api-call-organization-and-decoupling/#inject-it) by Alexander explains it even further
- Josh Deltener has a [great article](https://deltener.com/blog/nuxt-third-party-code-is-poison/) on how to import it properly too (with various approaches!)
- You could also use [this solution](https://dev.to/mandeepm91/how-to-add-third-party-scripts-inline-scripts-in-your-nuxt-js-app-1nbf) in your `nuxt.config.js` file (it's not that bad as you can see in the [github issues of Nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+dangerouslyDisableSanitizers))

```js
head: {
  __dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script'],
  script: [
    {
      hid: 'gtm-script1',
      src: 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-111111111-1',
      defer: true
    },
    {
      hid: 'gtm-script2',
      innerHTML: `
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-111111111-1');
      `,
      type: 'text/javascript',
      charset: 'utf-8'
    }
  ]
},
```

- Otherwise, you can also add it to a `app.html` at the root of your project

```html
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
   <head>
    {{ HEAD }} 
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}

    <!--EXTRA JS FILES-->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Answer to the initial answer

If you're adding it in the `nuxt.config.js` file, you need to directly use `process.env.SEGMENT_API_SECRET`.

May be a good idea to add this to some middleware or default layout than throwing directly some HTML into the config file.

Also, there is no point into adding it to `privateRuntimeConfig` if you are going to expose it anyway in the client. `privateRuntimeConfig` is **only** [used for server operations](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config#privateruntimeconfig) while building the app (on the Node.js side). In your case, Segment will be totally public and hence, you should be fine with exposing your public API key (double-check still).

---

EDIT: other you could also use the official [Nuxt](https://github.com/dansmaculotte/nuxt-segment) or [Vue](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-vue) plugin for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! No more error with that part, but now my snippet triggers other problems. I think my approach isn't the right one as you said. Initially I had my snippet in a `segment.js` located in the `static/ folder and that snippet was calling `process.env.SEGMENT_API_SECRET` but I had this error: "process is not defined", and `$config` isn't accessible there either. Any idea what's the proper way to do this with Nuxt.js?

Comment: Thanks @kissu I've seen these but I prefer not to use plugins for that as the native/standard/regular way is super straightforward. Also I'd like to know how to accomplish this because it might be useful for other APIs in which I need to include a snippet to my Nuxt.js app with a secret API key.

Comment: Thanks @kissu, the problem is none of these solutions deals with retrieving the API secret key stored in the `.env` file...!

Comment: It's explained in my initial answer, either use `process.env` directly or public runtime and access it through the context (`$config`).

Comment: Yes but I realized I can't paste the snippet in `nuxt.config.js` as in my question, it seems to creates many problems. Instead I need to a file containing the snippet, like in the article you linked https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/. But then in that file, I can't access either `process.env` or `$config`!

Comment: You can totally pass a `$config` with `export default ({ $axios, $config: { yourCoolEnvVariable } }) => { // your snippet }`

Comment: So in `static/segment.js` I added `export default ({ $axios, $config: { yourCoolEnvVariable } }) => { // your snippet }` and put my snippet where `// your snippet` is. I'm getting `Unexpected token 'export'` error.

Comment: Put it in plugins and import it in plugins (in `nuxt.config.js`).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but in my plugin `process.env.SEGMENT_API_SECRET` is `undefined` although I do have `SEGMENT_API_SECRET=FFD1k....ITUJS` in `.env` file. Also tried `publicRuntimeConfig: {  segmentApiSecret: process.env.SEGMENT_API_SECRET }` then to use `this.$config.segmentApiSecret` or `$config.segmentApiSecret` in my plugin, but `$config` is `undefined` there. What a pain in the neck..