# In Nuxtjs dynamic page's css and js isn't loading on page reload

Tags: javascript, css, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

When I open dynamic page first time in Nuxtjs it works fine but when I reload this page manually all of css and js files stop working and page breaks. When I open these styling and js files in browser from its page source, it shows " /* style not found */ " Can anyone guide me why its happening and what is its solution. My app's mode in universal.

This is my nuxt.config.js file ... these files in script tag are located in static/assets folder:

[image]

This is my issue:

[image]

This is happening because path for pages/project/id page is one directory up for static folder files but direct path for pages/ViewProject file .... I just don't know how I can make path same for all nested as well as direct pages. Can anyone guide me about this ?

Comment: Can you show us some code and also the `nuxt.config.js` file please.

Comment: script: [
      {
        src: `assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js`,
        body: true
      }]

Comment: Above is the script that is available in pages/viewProject page but not available in pages/project/viewProject. Its path issue that changes but I don't know how I can set this path that it don't change for nested pages. @kissu

Comment: Hm, this is not really helping me and is not representative of your bug.

Comment: What happens if you start all of your plugins paths with something like `'@/assets/js/...'`? `@` is basically saying "the root of my project", hence linking it in an _absolute_ way (from the root) rather than a _relative_ one (from your current component).

Comment: If all of those files are 3rd party scripts, you can maybe use my answer here (check `EDIT2`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585 Btw, I'm not sure `script` exists by itself.

Comment: I checked all of these solutions but didn't help :( .. anyways I added solution which worked for me. Hope it help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time searching on internet for solutions, finally I figured one solution. Posting it here so it may help anyone and saves anyone's time. So to make nuxt to not modify script paths by adding prefixes I included script src in head object of nuxt.config.js this way :

```
import { join } from 'path'
export default {
  head: {
         script: [
          {
            src: join('/', `assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js`),
            body: true
          }
    ]
}
```

This way now either from nested pages or direct pages under directory pages directory, script are loaded correctly.

Comment: VueSchool's solution did not worked (the one that I've linked)?