# How to correctly connect the module to the Head tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is such a js file that needs to be included in the `head` tag

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

After an incorrect (as I understand it) attempt to do this, I get the following result on the LAN:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

We can see that firstly there is some kind of `error` in the `head` tag.

Also, when trying to load this script at the end of the `body` tag
(this is done only for the purpose of experiment) - I cannot at least get a connection via an absolute path`(__nuxt/.....)`

Question:
What am I missing and how can I correctly connect the required `js` file?

Comment: What does the `network` tab show, in devtools?

Comment: The dev tools show the script was downloaded correctly into the network.
http://joxi.ru/D2PgJPYhBa86Bm
But if I go to nuxt-link on any internal pages - I will not have this script into the network dev tools.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a problem right now with not correctly working GTM.
I did I few ways(3) to connect it but all of these have the same bug.
GTM working on start page or if I do refresh page.
If I go with nuxt link on other pages - gtm not recognize it step and dont see it.
Maybe it happen because nuxt dont use downloading gtm after use nuxt-link at all. But I don't understand which approach should I use for solving this problem?

Comment: http://pokritijametallov.ru/
here is the project with this problem.

http://joxi.ru/zANMJPYs8KM4M2
right now it uses this approach for connecting GTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to add this kind of 3rd party scripts. You could either use a dedicated Nuxt module, sometimes plugins is also a good solution but if you want to have it directly embedded like this, you can follow my answer here with all the possible variants: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585