# Nuxt js How to import local js files from assets?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried all the ways to import the JS file and when i tried to navigate the script from the view source code it gives error "/* script not found */" .
i need to know what is the correct way to import local js scripts . 
below is the nuxt.config.js file .

```js
head: {
  title: 'admin',
  htmlAttrs: {
    lang: 'en'
  },
  meta: [
    { charset: 'utf-8' },
    { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
    { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
  ],
  link: [
    { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
  ],
  script: [
    {
      type: 'text/javascript',
      src: './assets/js/dashboard.js'
    },
    {
      type: 'text/javascript',
      src: '~/assets/plugins/charts-c3/plugin.js'
    },
    {
      type: 'text/javascript',
      src: '@/assets/plugins/maps-google/plugin.js'
    },
    {
      type: 'text/javascript',
      src: '/assets/plugins/input-mask/plugin.js'
    }
  ],
},
```

Comment: Did you tried importing it in `plugins` rather than `script`? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#the-plugins-property

Comment: actually it worked but its not in header

Comment: Why do you want it in the header? It's not really optimized.

Comment: If you really want it in `head`, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `plugins` key to import it globally to your Nuxt app (be careful of performance issues tho)

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-tooltip.js']
}
```

More info available here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#the-plugins-property

---

If you want to use some 3rd party scripts that should be available in the `header` (which is not the case from the code you shared so far), you could look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585)

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      { hid: 'stripe', src: 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', defer: true }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [Nuxt plugin property](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#la-propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9-plugins)

You can use the script property for externally available scripts (try to put it in your static directory and add it like it : `./my-scripts.js`

Comment: i tried the plugin property but its not inserting the script in header i will try the static directory

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Nuxt v3 RC** and updating `nuxt.config.js` did not help when using `NuxtLayout`.
I had to add the head to the `default.vue` layout to get external libraries to work.