# What is the best way to use MercadoPago in the NuxtJs?

Tags: javascript, laravel, nuxt.js, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I need to use SDK MercadoPago in the NuxtJs for payments, the form needs to be customizing, soo needs to use "checkout transparent", and i need to use payment with recorrency, to use subscriptions.

In this project NuxtJs is the front-end and Laravel is the back-end, Laravel is a API Rest, soo i need to save data from purchase like a Order, product name, quantity, price... in db when the checkout is success.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? SO is not a coding service and opinion-based questions are not allowed neither.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I tried add mercadopago.js in the vue component, but without success until now.. i searched how to use the api in the nuxt, but i wasn't successful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you tried to add it? With NPM or something else? Also, what is not working? Did you find some example on their documentation? Did you gave a look to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585)? Also, Nuxt's documentation is pretty good explaining how to interact with an API, in the most [conventional way](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#data-fetching) We'll need some code or issue to actually help you. Also, did you tried to give a look to this [github repo](https://github.com/andresdameson/nuxt-mercadopago-example), it should be a good start!