# What is the best way to embed Mailerlite forms in Nuxt JS

Tags: nuxt.js, embed

I want to embed Mailerlite forms on my Nuxt Js website.
Need the whole form to show up. (All fields)
Mailerlite gives 3 options: Javascript, HTML(with script) and Popup.

```html
<!-- MailerLite Universal -->
<div class="whole-form-here"></div>
<script>
  function ml_webform_success(){try{window.top.location.href="mysite.com/thank-you"}catch(o){window.location.href="mysite.com/thank-you"}}
</script>
<img src="https://track.mailerlite.com/webforms/o/" width="1" height="1" style="max-width:1px;max-height:1px;visibility:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;display:block" alt="." border="0">
<script src="https://static.mailerlite.com/js/w/webforms.min.js?" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End MailerLite Universal -->
```

Comment: Hi, does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585) help?

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Tell me if it helped, that way I'll post it as an answer.