# In nuxtJS, how to import native JS files in a single page

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I tried to import my local JS file in the "head" part of the nuxt.config.js file but failed. It is ok to import the "CDN" file in the same location

Comment: Hi, it's pretty cryptic as of what you want to include in your head. Especially without any code or [repro]. Give a look to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

Comment: Also, importing some code from a CDN may be okay, depending of the type of thing you're importing. Usually, it's better to install the package in your `node_modules` because it will be bundled and more optimized overall. But some things may be fine with a CDN too.

Comment: @kissu Finally, the corresponding plug-in was installed through NPM to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the package through NPM solved the issue.

On top of cleaning a bit the current codebase.