# jspdf doesn't work when loaded from a CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jspdf

I am going to use package([jspdf](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)) loaded from **CDN **

this is CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

and I have **loaded** it like this in a page :

```js
mounted() {
  if (document.getElementById('myScript')) { return }
  let src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js'
  let script = document.createElement('script')
  script.setAttribute('src', src)
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
  script.setAttribute('id', 'myScript')
  document.head.appendChild(script)
}
```

and I have a **button** that when you **click** on it a below **method** will called and some pdf will be generated.

```js
generateReport() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [62, 32])
  const margins = {
    top: 0,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 0,
    width: 122
  }

  doc.fromHTML(this.$refs.print, margins.left, margins.top, {
    width: margins.width
  })

  doc.save('test.pdf')
}
```

**BUT** I get an error

[image]

So, how can I **fix** this error?

Comment: You loaded the CDN but where is the jsPDF variable declaration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a 3rd party script code into Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534304/how-to-add-a-3rd-party-script-code-into-nuxt)

Comment: Also, are you sure that you want to use a CDN here? Pretty sure you can find the NPM package for that, it will be far better in a `package.json` tbh.

Comment: @DiesanRomero , variable declaration ? how can i do it ?

Comment: @kissu i a pretty sure that this way that i used cdn is worked because i can see that script is loaded , the problem is how to use it

Comment: Looks like the variable declaration is in generateReport(), `var doc = new jsPDF( ... )`. Possibly the class name is simply not spelled `jsPDF`. Have you checked the docs?

Comment: You should probably follow the [recommended install](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#install) and also the [recommended usage](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#usage). Otherwise, in "Other module formats, Globals", it's written `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;`. This way, you will get it out from the window. Still, even if it's loaded and feasible use it through an NPM package since it's more easy to control, more performant and less prone to a 404. And also because it's the recommended way from the package itself.

Comment: @GetSet i am sure class name is jsPDF() as written in doc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;` as shown in the [official documentation](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#other-module-formats) if you want to use the CDN.

Even tho, I **still** do recommend the NPM package way (so does the package itself).

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to be working :

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Super old version tho.