# Nuxt 3 Local JS Inclusion

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Running into a wall with Nuxt 3 and including local JS files. I converted an HTML template into a main Layout and several Components. Also added in the CSS supplied from the theme as global. The last part is to include the following local JS files supplied from the theme:

`custom.js, bootstrap.min.js, and slider.js`

I have tried adding them to the `nuxt.config.ts` within the head element, as plugins, and within the layout Component as well, but none of these methods seem to work. I can't seem to find a clean working answer for Nuxt 3.

Comment: Those are solutions for Nuxt2, but there is probably something viable for Nuxt3 too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

Answer (score 1):

In nuxt3 you can add global assets from components.

```
useHead({
  script: [{
    async: true,
    src: 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client',
    defer: true
  }]
})
```

For example from your main layout.

If you need more props for your script look at this interface:

```
interface ScriptBase {
    /**
     * For classic scripts, if the async attribute is present,
     * then the classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available.
     *
     * For module scripts,
     * if the async attribute is present then the scripts and all their dependencies will be executed in the defer queue,
     * therefore they will get fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as they are available.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async
     */
    async?: Booleanable;
    /**
     * Normal script elements pass minimal information to the window.onerror
     * for scripts which do not pass the standard CORS checks.
     * To allow error logging for sites which use a separate domain for static media, use this attribute.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-crossorigin
     */
    crossorigin?: '' | 'anonymous' | 'use-credentials';
    /**
     * This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document
     * has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer
     */
    defer?: Booleanable;
    /**
     * Provides a hint of the relative priority to use when fetching an external script.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-fetchpriority
     */
    fetchpriority?: 'high' | 'low' | 'auto';
    /**
     * This attribute contains inline metadata that a user agent can use to verify
     * that a fetched resource has been delivered free of unexpected manipulation.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-integrity
     */
    integrity?: string;
    /**
     * This Boolean attribute is set to indicate that the script should not be executed in browsers
     * that support ES modules — in effect,
     * this can be used to serve fallback scripts to older browsers that do not support modular JavaScript code.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-nomodule
     */
    nomodule?: Booleanable;
    /**
     * A cryptographic nonce (number used once) to allow scripts in a script-src Content-Security-Policy.
     * The server must generate a unique nonce value each time it transmits a policy.
     * It is critical to provide a nonce that cannot be guessed as bypassing a resource's policy is otherwise trivial.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-nonce
     */
    nonce?: string;
    /**
     * Indicates which referrer to send when fetching the script, or resources fetched by the script.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-referrerpolicy
     */
    referrerpolicy?: ReferrerPolicy;
    /**
     * This attribute specifies the URI of an external script;
     * this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src
     */
    src?: string;
    /**
     * This attribute indicates the type of script represented.
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type
     */
    type?: '' | 'text/javascript' | 'module' | 'application/json' | 'application/ld+json' | 'speculationrules' | (string & Record<never, never>);
    /**
     * This attribute defines the unique ID.
     */
    id?: string;
}
type Script = ScriptBase & HttpEventAttributes;
```

You can use `/public` directory for your files and append them using relative patch.

Comment: `/public` worked for me.