# How to add a script block to head in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I simply want to add a `script` block in the `head` tag.

**Example**

```js
<script>
    alert('hello, world!');
</script>
```

I spent hours to figure out a solution for something as simple as this.
There are tons of answers about adding `inline` scripts, but none for the script `block` for `Nuxt 3`

How can we do this in `Nuxt 3`?

Comment: This was [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585) for nuxt2. Here is the related topic for Nuxt3: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/5565

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. There are 3 possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

```
<template>
  <Script children="console.log('Hello, world!');" />
</template>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<script setup>
useHead({
  script: [{ children: "console.log('Hello, world!');" }],
});
</script>
```

**Solution 3**

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      script: [{ children: "console.log('Hello, world!');" }],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The first one is maybe working but hacky as hell, the second one is the most recommended way overall. You're welcome for the third one!

Comment: why do we need a children's to object?  and can  you put a immediately invoked function there?

Comment: Solution 3 works amid webpage hard refresh