# What is the best way to add scripts in Nuxt 3, for SSG pages?

Tags: nuxtjs3, ssg

I am porting over an older website into Nuxt 3.  This older website has numerous `<script>` tags referring to local .js files. The intent is to generate pages using Nuxt3's SSG functionality to host the site, so any optimization Nuxt 3 can provide would be the preferred method. What is the best way to include these scripts?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

Comment: And also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72848779/8816585

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I have seen some of these. Most of the instructions are for Nuxt 2, and some of them have changed.   

Also, for Nuxt 2/3 I have seen many conflicting ways to do this, as plugins/, as modules/ as head <script>s, in assets/ whether in public/ (former static/ directory in Nuxt 2).   Wanted to know if there was a "best way to do this" in case there are optimizations I get when generating SSG pages.

Will look at these examples further, but still unclear to me if there is a "best" way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Best way would be to do it locally in a single `.vue` file. Modules and plugins are fine too but it will be global, so not the best. Head `script` is probably the worst (especially if remote). `assets` would be okay I guess and `public` I don't really see the point tbh (especially because not bundled).