# Integrate frontchat with Nuxt

Tags: null, nuxt.js, client-side, appendchild, github-third-party-apps

I am integrating the front app with my nuxt site. It's already working fine with my previous vue site. Add the bundle in the script tag of the **nuxt.config.js** file.

```
  head: {
   script: [{ src: 'https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js' }]
  },
```

I am integrating the rest of the script in the **Pages/index.vue** file. Like that

```
if (process.client) {
  window.FrontChat('init', {
  chatId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  useDefaultLauncher: true
});
}
```

Its giving me this warning & error.
[image]

Comment: Nuxt2 or 3? You cannot use an NPM package rather than a CDN?

Comment: For Nuxt2, check that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

Comment: @kissu I am using the Nuxt2, and I think there is no mistake in it. I don't know why this error only comes in nuxt. This is not an NPM package.

Comment: Quite a shame if no NPM package. Otherwise, my previous comment is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by just adding body: true because the

> Front Chat script should be positioned just before the closing body
> tag.

```js
head: {
  script: [{ 
    src: 'https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js' 
    body: true, 
  }]
},
```